# My new release not getting browsed in browser post update

Tags: apache, web, akamai

I have a website hosted in Apache. its a spring framework application uses angular for front end.
This is being accessed through akamai technology. I have updated the application hosted in the origin server.
When I tried to access from browser it gives a blank page. After doing an 'CTRL + F5' its gives me proper website.
I am not able to sort this out why such behavior in the application. Can any expert in this help me out.

Thanks In advance
Bala

Answer (score 1):

Your page might be cached in your browser. I'd recommend that you could check "cache-control" HTTP response header, e.g.

```
cache-control: max-age=0, no-cache
```

It can be controlled by either Akamai or Apache.